# Add A UIButton At The End Of A View With Dynamic Height

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uibutton

I have a `UIView` containing `UIWebView` and a `UILabel.` This `UIView` is added inside a `UIScrollView.` Since the `UIWebView` has dynamic height, so the `UIScrollView` changes its height accordingly. The whole things works fine and all is done in storyboards.

Now i need to add a `UIButton` at the end of the `UIWebView` or after it. I cannot just drag and drop a button in StoryBoard as it stays at the fixed position.

What i want is when the scroll ends, there at the bottom a `UIButton` should appear. How can i achieve that?

[image: UIVIEW UIButton]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Button **y** position will be Label_Height+Webview_Height+(Margin_between_webview_and_button)
So,Accordingly scrollview content height will be Label_Height+WebView_Height+Button_Height

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[button addTarget:self
           action:@selector(aMethod:)
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[button setTitle:@"This is a button" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, height, 160.0, 40.0);
[self.webView addSubview:button];
```

In the second last line of the above code, "height" is the height of the webview as you have already retrieved that. Just adding the height of the webview and adding the button as the subview of the webview will work.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add `UIButton` at the bottom of `UIWebView` than change your button frame like below.

```
 `button.frame.origin.y = webview.frame.origin.y + webview.frame.size.height;`

 Implement the above line after you get the finally webview height dynamically and set `UIScrollView` `contentsize` accordingly.

 `[scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(scrollview.frame.size.width,button.frame.origin.y + button.frame.size.height )];`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can inject html like `<a href='myTag01'> <button>Button </button> </a>` into the content of the webview using stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString method.

To capture the click event and prevent it from reloading content of your webview use this delegate:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    if(navigationType==UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked && [[request.URL absoluteString] isEqualToString: @"yourTag01"])
    {
        //your custom action code goes here
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try dragging UIButton to your UIScrollView and set its autoresize mask in xib to BOTTOM 
Just check mark bottom line and that should work, remove other marks inside box and just keep one red line in bottom active. This should work. Check it out

[image]

Comment: already tried that but it scrolls with the scroll view also it shows the button even when the webview is not loaded up. I want the button where the content of the UIWebView ends.

Comment: Then you need to do that programmatically. That is the only way you can do it

Answer (score 0):

First add the UIScrollView delegate to your header file like this

```
@interface ScrollView : UIScrollView <UIScrollViewDelegate>
```

Then add this delegate method in your implementation file:

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
     if (scrollView.contentOffset.y >= scrollView.contentSize.width) {
         // Add a UIButton
     }

}
```

Comment: Nothing happens by doing the code you mentioned. Tried adding the button in different view but still it doesn't show anything